# How to use setInterval() method to stop after executing function after "n" times

Tags: angular, typescript

How can use the `setInterval()` to call the function at the given time interval and to stop the execution of the program when the counter hits 40.

I implemented the below logic the counter gets incremented to 2 and goes to infinite loop

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  intervalcounter :any;
  intervalsDef :any;

  ngOnInit(){
    this.intervalcounter = 1;
    this.function_with_interval();
  }


  function_with_interval(){

    this.intervalsDef =setInterval(()=> {
      console.log(this.intervalcounter);
      this.getData(); },10);

    if(this.intervalcounter == 40){
      console.log(this.intervalcounter);
      clearInterval(this.intervalsDef);
    }
    else{
      this.intervalcounter++;
      console.log(this.intervalcounter);
    }


     
    }

    getData(){
      console.log("hello")
    }
  }
```

stackblitz edit link : [application edit link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-u27zx1?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: I would prefer to use interval operator provided by rxjs is better than setInterval provided by the DOM API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking for the function call count outside the function scheduled with `setInterval`. Inside the context of that function, it doesn't know that it should stop executing, while the `if...else` part which checks for the call count is executed only once.

Try this:

```
import { Component, VERSION, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  intervalCounter: number;
  intervalID: number;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.intervalCounter = 1;
    this.function_with_interval();
  }

  incrementCounter(step = 1) {
    this.intervalCounter += step;
  }

  function_with_interval() {
    this.intervalID = setInterval(() => {
      console.log(++this.intervalCounter);
      this.getData();

      if (this.intervalCounter >= 4) {
        clearInterval(this.intervalID);
      }
    }, 1000);
  }

  getData() {
    console.log('hello');
  }
}
```

Check out the working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-i3mnge?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

PS. never use `any` type. You are bypassing all the benefits of typescript when you do that.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this and it should work. Use IF ELSE inside the interval.

```
function_with_interval(){

    this.intervalsDef =setInterval(()=> {
      if(this.intervalcounter == 40){
        console.log(this.intervalcounter);
        clearInterval(this.intervalsDef);
      }
      else{
        this.intervalcounter++;
        console.log(this.intervalcounter);
      }
      console.log(this.intervalcounter);
      this.getData(); },10);

   


     
    }
```

Here is the link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-plkhwq?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Format your code.   Your indentations are misleading, the only thing executed on your interval is the `console.log` and the call to `getData()`.  The rest of the code in your function is only called the when you first call the function, not at each interval.

```
    this.intervalsDef =setInterval(()=> {
      console.log(this.intervalcounter);
      this.getData(); },10);
```

Formatted properly it is easy to see:

```
this.intervalsDef = setInterval(() => {
  console.log(this.intervalcounter);
  this.getData();
}, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like mentioned in comment, if you want to switch to use rxjs instead, which I recommend, your code get considerably shorter as well ;) So just to throw this out there:

So, run interval every 10 milliseconds, do that 40 times as per your example:

```ts
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { interval } from 'rxjs';

//.... more code....

ngOnInit() {
  interval(10).pipe(take(40)).subscribe(() => this.getData())
}

getData(){
  console.log("hello")
}
```

That's it! As we are using `take`, we don't need to unsubscribe either, as that is handled by `take`.

Comment: Presumably milliseconds is not 10 and getData perhaps does an api call, if so, look into switchMap. But it is outside the scope of this question.